# Timer counts instantly instead of respecting interval

Tags: swift

Im trying to make a countdown timer. everything works fine except that my timer does not count at regular intervals (1sec); instead it counts all the way down instantly giving me 0 every time. did a lot of search without luck. All examples I could find show similar timeInterval parameter.

```
var timer = Timer()
var remainingTime = 120

@objc func timerCount () {
    if remainingTime > 0 {
        while remainingTime > 0 {
            remainingTime -= 1
            timerLabel.text = String(remainingTime)
            print(remainingTime)
        }
    } else {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}

@IBAction func pauseButton(_ sender: Any) {
    timer.invalidate()
}

@IBAction func playButton(_ sender: Any) {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.timerCount), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

Comment: Did you *debug* your code? What is the purpose of the `while remainingTime > 0` loop? What do you think that it does?

Comment: that's the loop to count down - 1 every interval triggered by the playbutton action. issue is the loop is supposed to trigger every 1 sec interval as specified in the timeInterval parameter but it executes all in one go

Comment: `timerCount()` is called every second. There is no need for the while-loop. It instantly counts down to zero.

Comment: AMAZING ! just removed the while loop as you suggested :) I did not realise it was not needed. basically the timer function is a while loop in itself.. Thanks !

Comment: @MartinR would you know why my timer "stacks up" thus accelerating if I press my play button multiple times ?

Comment: Because you create a new timer and don't invalidate the existing one.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it by using an if statement with a variable set to 1 if the play button has been pressed and set to 0 if the stop button is pressed. I guess I could also have added an invalidate timer at the beginning of the play button but I like complicated :D

Comment: if you have a **repeating** Timer, then your timerInterval must be set to 60 or more seconds. Otherwise you would get a runtime error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code is not working is that you have put an unnecessary while loop in your **timerCount()** method. You don't need to do this. Your timer will fire this method after each time interval. At very first call this while loop make your remainingTime to 0. This is why you are instantly getting 0 every time.

You just need to remove that while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Can You try  like this

```
var timer = Timer()
var remainingTime = 120

@objc func timerCount () {
    let date = NSDate()

    let nowdate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "NowDate") as! Date


    let miniute = nowdate.timeIntervalSince(date as Date)

    print(Int(miniute))

    if (Int(miniute) == 0) {

        timer.invalidate()
         UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "NowDate")

    } else {
        timerLabel.text = String(Int(miniute))
    }
}

@IBAction func pauseButton(_ sender: Any) {
    timer.invalidate()
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "NowDate")

}

@IBAction func playButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let CurrentDate = NSDate()

    let NowDate = CurrentDate.addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(remainingTime))

    UserDefaults.standard.set(NowDate, forKey: "NowDate")

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.timerCount), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

Comment: thank you but I'm really trying to understand why my code is not working first :)